# Wrap text in figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I've been using wrapfig to wrap text over a figure, but if I have an image like this:

[image]

Can I get this result?

Comment: `\parshape`? There will be lot of manual adjustment.

Comment: Ok, but how do I use that?

Comment: Is is an external image or something done in Latex?

Comment: It's done with CorelDraw.

Comment: Can you include it in your question? I mean the original image.

Comment: Yo can take a look at the documentation of the [shapepar](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) package. That said, that kind of digure is easy to do with `pstricks` or `tikz`.

Comment: Possibly http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz?

Answer (score 3):

Here, after downloading your image as EJCmE.jpg, I just place a `\parshape`d `minipage` inside of a `\stackinset` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,shapepar,graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{1cm}{t}{.78cm}{\begin{minipage}[t]{6.8cm}
\color{cyan!40}\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{18pt}{29pt}\selectfont \parshape 3
0cm 6.8cm
1.6cm 5.2cm
4.4cm 2.4cm
text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{minipage}}{%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{EJCmE}}
\end{document}
```

[image]